# how to populate select dropdown values ANGULAR 8

Tags: angular

I have a edit button

```html
<button (click)="valueFunction(data, template)"> EDIT</button>
```

this is my function for button in TS

```js
valueFunction(data, template) {
  this.openModal(template);
  console.log(data);
}
```

when the button is clicked, there is a pop up, with select dropdown.

this is my dropdown in pop up template

```html
      <ng-template #template>
        <div >
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th ">value of a/th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td >
              <select
                    required
                    formControlName="vals"
                    (change)="onChange($event)"
                     class="form-control" >

                     <option>1</option >
                     <option>2</option >
                     <option>3</option >
                     <option>4</option >

                 </select>
                </td>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>

          <div>
            <span>update ?</span>
          </div>

          <button

            (click)="confirm()"
          >
            Yes
          </button>

        </div>
      </ng-template>
```

This dropdown should show saved options values.
suppose 1, 2, 3 ,4 are the options in this select dropdown, and I had chosen 2 previously and "updated" the page, now when i open this pop up again I want option 2 to show already selected.

Ts file, this is the value i get, when i select something from dropdown

```js
public onChange(event): void {
  const a = event.target.value;

  console.log("value of a :", a);
}
```

Comment: Whenever the selection changes, you want to create a new span in the UI, and those spans should be clickable to open up a modal. Am I correct?

Comment: Please elaborate on how the <select> and the valueFuction + click belong to each other and what you want to achieve

Comment: Please include what kind of issue you are facing.Also provide entire components, not some specific functions.

Comment: I edited the question and added details

Comment: What do you mean with "updated" the page"? Do you mean a page refresh?

Comment: update as in saved the data, after pressing the button

Comment: now data is saved in database, and when i open the pop up again, it should show the same data in the select dropdown that i previously saved

Comment: @RakshandaBhure you've not given any indication about how the data is saved and loaded, or what `dropdownVals is. There is not enough information here.

Comment: dropdown vals, is just a list of options that appear in the slelect, my options are 1, 2, 3, 4